# Understanding the behaviour of different variations of Binary Search

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, binary-search, intuition

Binary Search is a fairly simple and standard algorithm that can be used (among other things) to find a target element in a sorted array. There are subtle variations in code to do this, however all of them work the same for the case in which an element exists for the most part.

The subtleties that I'm trying to wrap my head around exist in the cases where the element is *not* found in the array. The behaviour of what index/element *is* returned varies greatly.

For example, the simplest way of writing binary search (taken from wikipedia):

```
function binary_search(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n − 1
    while L <= R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T:
            L := m + 1
        else if A[m] > T:
            R := m - 1
        else:
            return m
    return unsuccessful
```

finishes randomly on either side of where the target element *would have been* in the array depending on the array itself.

For deterministic behaviour of where the search stops always (also phrased as determining the rank of the element in the array), there are subtle variations in procedures, which change the control flow, for example (also taken from wikipedia):

```
function binary_search_leftmost(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T:
            L := m + 1
        else:
            R := m
    return L
```

Or

```
function binary_search_rightmost(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] > T:
            R := m
        else:
            L := m + 1
    return L - 1
```

There are variations in:

- using `floor` vs `ceil`
- variation in how the control flows in case of `A[m]  == T` (`A[m] ≥ T` clause vs `A[m] ≤ T` clause)
- which element is returned (`L` vs `L-1`)

I understand that both these also have differences in how they behave in cases where the target is duplicated in the array also.

However I'm trying to figure out the intuition behind the various differences introduced and how they add up to the deterministic behaviour that they produce. I can of course run arrays through these by hand and see that they are of course correct, however - why?

Comment: Check this https://blog.domfarolino.com/Binary-Search-Useful-Variants/